# Can not use theme color with text or bg

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I overwrite bootstrap's `theme-colors` in my scss file, as following

```
// set variables
$primary: #8dc3a7;
$light: #b4d6c1;
$starorange: #df711b;

// import functions and variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

$custom-theme-colors: (
  "starorange": $starorange,
);

// modify theme colors
$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);

// bootstrap import
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I can use `starorange` color in a button as the following and it is applying the color properly

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-starorange">Send</button>
```

However I can **not** use the same color in the same HTML document for text or bg as in the following.

```
<div class="pb-1 text-starorange">
    <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
    <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
    <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
    <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
    <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
</div>
```

or

```
<section class="bg-starorange">
     .... some html here ...
</section>
```

So, both of the above two examples have no effect in the output, I mean the color is not applied at all. I don't understand why this happens, any help would be appreciated.

PS: There is no `bg-starorange`, `text-starorange` in the transpiled css file, but `btn-starorange`, `border-starorange` or `link-starorange` somehow exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recently answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755179/bootstrap-5-custom-theme-colors-not-updating-classes/68762902#68762902), but there does seem to be a [new issue introduced in 5.1.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34756) because of this change mentioned on the Bootstrap blog...

> "**Updated .bg- and .text- utilities**
> Our new RGB values are built to help us make better use of CSS variables across the entire project. To start, our background-color and color utilities have been updated to use these new RGB values for real-time customization without recompiling Sass and on-the-fly transparency for any background or text color."

Currently in 5.1.0 you'd need to rebuild all the bg-* and text-* classes like this...

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

$starorange: #df711b;

$custom-theme-colors: (
  "starorange": $starorange
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, $theme-colors-rgb);
$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");

@import "bootstrap";
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/oPZJTugU9m)

---

Update for Bootstrap 5.1.x -- the issue with custom `bg-` and `text-` colors will be fixed in 5.2.x per: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35297

Answer (score 0):

The response above by @zim almost worked for me.  The problem is it wiped out the -white -black and -body variations on generated utilities.

I was able to get my additional theme colors correctly added with:

```
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";

// Additional Theme Colors
$theme-colors:map-merge($theme-colors, (
  "brand-primary":$brand-primary,
  "brand-primary-light":$brand-primary-light,
  "brand-primary-dark":$brand-primary-dark,
  "brand-neutral-dark":$brand-neutral-dark,
  "brand-neutral-medium":$brand-neutral-medium,
  "brand-neutral-light":$brand-neutral-light,));

$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, $theme-colors-rgb);
$utilities-colors: map-merge($utilities-colors, (
    "black": to-rgb($black),
    "white": to-rgb($white),
    "body": to-rgb($body-color)
));
$utilities-text-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "text");
$utilities-bg-colors: map-loop($utilities-colors, rgba-css-var, "$key", "bg");

@import "bootstrap";
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't 100% "right" though.  Looking at bootstraps variables.scss white/black/body should be added back in to $utilities-text and $utilities-bg while this adds it to all utilities. For my needs I can live with it but to be more proper it looks like you'd only want to add them to the $utilities-text-colors and $utilities-bg-colors - but when I try that I loose black for some reason.

And I've spent too long on this today.  It looks like it should be [fixed in the next release](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/34942) so I'm just going to hold off updating until then since that's an option for me.