# Bootstrap 5 - bg-customcolor and text-customcolor not working

Tags: css, sass, background-color, bootstrap-5

I was updating an old bootstrap page to the new Bootstrap 5.3.1. - following this great instruction, I've set up my custom colors: [How to extend/modify (customize) Bootstrap with SASS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776055/how-to-extend-modify-customize-bootstrap-with-sass/49070142)

Now (what I don't understand): bg-fun-pink and text-fun-pink is not working although the color ("fun-pink") works on buttons (btn-fun-pink).

What did I wrong so the bg-color of a div and / or the text-color is not changing?

See my example on codeply: https://www.codeply.com/p/ZT1yZA56QH

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code is on codeply...

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/understrap/understrap/pull/1640) that will be fixed in Bootstrap 5.2

However I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68762902/11472732) that might help?

And the original fix described [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/35297#issuecomment-955070232).