# Undefined variable $theme-colors-rgb in Bootstrap root.scss

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use some parts of Bootstrap 5.2 within my Angular project. It is configured for SASS and so I am importing the scss files for Bootstrap within the main style.scss of the project. I am doing this as I am using Angular Material and so only want the Bootstrap Grid and some other basic parts.

Currently I have

**style.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

I am only including the root.scss as this is as described in the Bootstrap docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#variable-defaults) but removing it makes the ng build ONLY fail within the grid.scss as the $gutters variable is undefined. With it included however the output of ng build is:

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
20 │   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb {
   │                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_root.scss 20:27  @import
  src\styles.scss 22:9                          root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
20 │   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors-rgb {
   │                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_root.scss 20:27  @import
  src\styles.scss 22:9                          root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
    ╷
114 │       @each $key, $value in $gutters {
    │                             ^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 114:29       @content
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
  src\styles.scss 26:9                                       root stylesheet
```

Any help would be appreciated as the articles I've read suggest doing what I have done but obviously theirs work :)

https://www.amadousall.com/the-best-parts-of-bootstrap-you-are-missing-in-angular-material/

**UPDATE**

Using this [Bootstrap 5 - Custom theme-colors not updating classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755179/bootstrap-5-custom-theme-colors-not-updating-classes)
the following change (Though I don't want a tertiary colour) removes the error of an undefined $theme-colors-rgb but the $gutters issue remains

**style.scss**

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$tertiary: #3fb247;

$custom-theme-colors:map-merge($theme-colors, (
  "tertiary": $tertiary
));

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-theme-colors);
$theme-colors-rgb: map-loop($theme-colors, to-rgb, "$value");

@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

Comment: have you tried to import files like `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions"`

Comment: Hi @debugger - I have. I don't think the problem is that the files are not being found/imported

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5.2**

I think you need to add `@import "~bootstrap/scss/maps"` because there is a new [_maps.scss in version 5.2](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#new-_mapsscss) where the following properties have been shifted :

`$theme-colors-rgb`

`$utilities-colors`

`$utilities-text`

`$utilities-text-colors`

`$utilities-bg`

`$utilities-bg-colors`

`$negative-spacers`

`$gutters`

Comment: Wow - thanks @debugger - I didnt find that suggesting anywhere in my searching. It works now - and I can remove the extra code I added in the update I made to my post! Most grateful

Comment: Thanks, I was also missing this import since I was upgrading from 4 to 5

Comment: Awesome how their own documentation doesn't mention this..thanks

Comment: @debugger, where do I have to put that import line?

Comment: @MatiasNovillo add it right after the imports of `variables` and `mixins` but before `root`.

Answer (score 13):

As of Bootstrap v5.3 this is how I was able to get it to work and the order is important:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables-dark';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/maps';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/utilities';
```

Comment: You can see the order Bootstrap puts them in in their [bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/bootstrap.scss) file.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks @AdamJohnson, couldn't get it to work using the bootstrap documentation either.  Had to do trial and error to get this order.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to the accepted answer, can't edit or comment on it.

After upgrading to 5.3.0 you also have to @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables-dark". And it looks like it's not changing according to this github issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/38683